# Expressjs Audio Stream not being played when requested

Tags: javascript, express, streaming, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm building a mobile music app, which consumes an Expressjs API, and I'm having trouble sending the song to the client via streaming.

I have a `songs` route in my express app:

```js
import express from 'express'

import fs from 'fs'

const router = express.Router()
router.get(
    '/:fileName',
    async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        try {
            const { fileName } = req.params
            const filePath = `music/${fileName}`
            const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            const stat = fs.statSync(filePath)

            res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${filePath}"`)
            res.set('Content-Range', `bytes ${0}-${stat.size - 1}/${stat.size}`)
            res.set('Content-Length', `${stat.size}`)

            res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
            res.set('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')

            stream.pipe(res)
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err)
        }
    }
)

module.exports = router
```

And my mobile app is built with React and uses `react-native-track-player`.
For some reason, the audio is not being played, not only in my mobile app but also in the browser or even PostMan

In the Browser:

[image: browser doesn't play audio aswell]

and in PostMan, it also asks me to download a `.mpga` file:

[image]

If a get another link, from Google Drive for instance, the audio is playable, and it works in my mobile app.

Google Drive Link on PostMan:

[image]

I'm stuck on this for weeks. Any idea how it could be solved? Thank you, in advance.

## UPDATE

With `ogg` files, the stream works just fine.
I wonder why it doesn't with `mp3`. If you have any idea, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to access the variable in the parameters so

```
req.params
```

should be converted to

```
req.params[0]
```

in order to access the file passed from the params.
as stated in the Express API:

```
// GET /file/javascripts/jquery.js
console.dir(req.params[0])
// => 'javascripts/jquery.js'
```

Comment: That's not right, `request.params` returns a Dictiorary.
In my case: 
`{ fileName: 'song.mp3' }` 

I don't get any errors related to a non existing file. In fact, I don't get any errors. The song is just not being played at all.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're handling content ranges is wrong.

```
res.set('Content-Range', `bytes ${0}-${stat.size - 1}/${stat.size}`)
```

You've hard-coded the start range, but it's regularly the case that the range requested doesn't always start at `0`.

I'd strongly recommend simply using `express.static()` in this case, or even a regular web server like Nginx.  It already does the work for you.

Additionally, your code has a serious security vulnerability in that anyone can basically request any file on your hard drive by passing in relative paths `../../../etc`.